# how to get CSS drop down menus to stay open even when clicked outside the menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, click

I have a request from a customer to handle their drop down menu system. I have the menus working as drop downs but they requested that the drop downs happen not on a hover, but must be "clicked" to display them, even all the crazy sub menus.

Furthermore, they want the menus to stay open (pinned) in their revealed state even if the top level nav item is closed. I know it's strange behaviour but it's what they want. It should be noted that only one top nab menu item should be open at any time.
They are employing an iframe to display the hrefs so we don't need cookies to save the state of the menus at this time but it would be nice for the future ;)
I'm not a javascript person, this was cobbled together from code I gathered but I'm at a loss. I did manage to change a bit of JS at one time to handle opening the menus via a click but once the mouse moved out of the ULs it would disappear.

I've posted my code so far here: http://jsfiddle.net/9dJ9T/8/

Can anyone get the menus to only display when clicked and stay opened and "pinned" until they are all subsequently "unpinned"?  Ideally I think jquery .toggle method would be better but this menu system has so many UL and LIs in it I can't imagine creating functions of each and every one!!  Is there a way such a function could be abstracted to simplify the code and not end up with a huge list of functions?  I'm eager to learn from the JS masters!!

Comment: Is _all_ of that code really necessary?  There's a lot of unrelated CSS and JS in there, making help a much more daunting task.  Can you reduce the code to only that which reproduces the issue?

Comment: In general, you'll probably want to: 1) Remove the CSS-based `:hover` effect; 2) Add a jQuery `.click()` handler to the menu items to toggle the sub-menus.  That latter part _should_ only be for the top-level items, so it's not terrible to manually bind each event.  But if you want to make it more of a pattern, you'd just need to have a selector for all of the top-level menu elements and, for each one, have a way to identify its sub-menu element.

Comment: I agree with @David . You should remove more of your example code and distill it down to just one menu item, with a couple sub menu items. That will make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Thanks David. I can clean it up a bit but I need to know if I need to add a .click function to each sub menu? There are quite a few in there. Isn't there a way to write a function to target sub menus individually or do I need to add IDs to each in order to target them with a simple routine?  Sorry about all the extra code in there, I just pasted in everything I had to make sure it worked so you could see the end result.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need all that. Remake it. You can solve that in like 10 lines.

Add something like onclick="displaySubmenu('someIdOrSomethingOrWhateverYouWant');" on each tab.

The js must be something like

```
    function displaySubmenu(el)
    {
         // Hide all elements. (Easy to do)
         // Display the needed one. (document.getElementById('yourSetedId').style.display ='block');
    }
```

The rest is css and html.

If you wanna keep the fade just keep that function and set it on your id.

Answer (score 0):

The easy part is just opening the right one and closing the others

```
$(".dropTab").on("click", function(){
    $(".dropTab").hide();
    $(this).show();
})
```

the bit more complicated part is where the tab should close when the user clicks outside any menu area, like just on the main content.

```
$("body").on("click",function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).closest(".headerBar").length) { 
        return;
    }

    $(".dropTab").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<div class="btn-group" id="myDropdown"><a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Menu<span class="caret"></span></a><ul class="dropdown-menu"><li><a href="#">Choice1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Choice2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Choice3</a></li>
<li class="divider"></li>
<li><a href="#">Choice..</a></li></ul></div>
```

and the js

```
$('#myDropdown').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function () {
return false;
```

});